# if statements or while loop conditions?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, statements

So for an assignment, I'm supposed to write a function that evaluates two other functions that I previously defined in the program. How, the intricacies of this next function I must define is confusing me how I should set it up. Basically, I have determined that I have to write a while loop, but I can't decide whether to have three different conditions or if statements to evaluate this function. The thing is, the loop must end after one of the three conditions is met; I just don't know how to lay it out currently. 
These are the three conditions (where only one must be met in order for the loop/function to terminate):

1. the  absolute    value   of  the polynomial  at  the current estimate    is  less    than    epsilon,    in
   which   case    the method  is  successful.
2. the  absolute    value   of  the derivative  of  the polynomial  at  the current estimate    is  less
   than    epsilon (this   could   lead    to  division    by  0), in  which   case    the method  failed, or
3. the  number  of  revisions   of  the estimate    has exceeded    timeout (the    estimate    is  not 
   converging  on  a   solution). This case    is  also    a   failure.

This is currently what I have as my code (and it hasn't been running obviously):

```
def newtonsMethod(poly, x_, epislon, timeout):
    """Calculating root of polynomial using newton's Method."""
    estimate = 0
    epislon = 1e-20
    while (abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x_)) < epislon and \
abs(evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly), x_)) and estimate > timeout):
        estimate = x_ - (evaluatePoly(poly) / evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly)))
         x_ = estimate
         print(x_)
```

How should I go about this? The function name is a requirement of the assignment so it cannot be changed. Also, I am a complete beginner at this stuff (just started last month) and I'm only basically required to have knowledge of data structures, loops, and if statements (and functions). So please keep your responses as simple/dumby proof as possible.

This is all the code I have before that pertains to this question:

```
def findDerivative(poly):
    """Find the derivative of the polynomial and return it as a list of 
    coefficents"""
    count = 0
    polyList = []
    for nn in poly:
        polyList += [nn * count]
        count += 1
    return polyList[1:]

def evaluatePoly(poly, x_):
    """Evaluates the polynomial at x = x_ and returns the result as a   floating-
    point number using Horner's rule"""
    #http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html
    count = 0
    polyEval = []
    for nn in poly:
        xVal = x_**count
        polyEval += [xVal * nn]
        count += 1
    polySum = sum(polyEval)
    return float(polySum)
```

Edit: 10/23/2016

I should have mentioned this before or explained the assignment in more detail, but estimate is a parameter for the function because it is given as a list later on in the assignment. I have understood that timeout represents that the loop can run through so many times before it "breaks" or ends. The function is to return a two-part tuple where the first  variable of the tuple is the refined x_ value and the second variable is a boolean value saying whether the method was successful or not. Using advice from both @Blckknght and @David Bowling , I was able to refine my code to the following:

```
def newtonsMethod(poly, x_, epsilon, timeout):
    """Calculating root of polynomial using newton's Method."""
    deriv_poly = findDerivative(poly)
    deriv = evaluatePoly(deriv_poly, x_)
    value = evaluatePoly(poly, x_)
    count = 1
    while True:
        x_ -= value / deriv
        if abs(value) < epsilon:
            boolean = abs(value) < epsilon
            xTuple = (x_, boolean)
            return xTuple
        if abs(deriv) < epsilon or count > timeout:
            boolean = abs(deriv) < epsilon or count > timeout
            xTuple = (x_, boolean)
            return xTuple
        count += 1
```

However, I am still experiencing crashing problems when I run the code. I realized belatedly that I cannot have both boolean variables to equal to True (for my following code, I need boolean to equal True or False) but in order for the loop to stop, one of the if statements must equal True. 
I apologize for all the confusion and specifications this code requires; I hope this explanation helps understanding what I need.

Comment: Long `while()` conditions are hard to read. It will be simpler if you use `while True:` and then use separate `if` statements that run `break` when the termination condition is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice given by others to break up your complicated conditional into simpler statements is very good. The logic in your original conditional was faulty, but could be adjusted to work. Yet there were other problems in your function.

There is no need to assign `epsilon` a value before the loop, because this value is supplied as a function parameter. `estimate` should be functioning as a counter, but then confusingly gets assigned the value to be used for `x_` in the next iteration. I have renamed `estimate` as `iterations` in my code below.

You should have used:

```
abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x_)) > epsilon
```

since you want the loop to continue so long as the value of the polynomial evaluated at `x_` is larger than `epsilon`. And, to avoid difficulties in the statement that updates the value of `x_`, you want to continue looping only if:

```
abs(evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly), x_)) > epsilon
```

There was a missing conditional here in your original code. Finally, you want to continue looping if the number of `iterations` has not yet reached the `timeout` value. You only want to loop if all of the above conditions are met, so your conditional expression should be:

```
while abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x_)) > epsilon and \
          abs(evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly), x_)) > epsilon and \
          iterations < timeout:
```

I changed your next assignment statement in two ways. First, the assignment is now made to `x_` instead of the old, confusing `estimate` variable. Second, you were missing the second argument in both of the `evaluatePoly()` functions. I added a line to increment the `iterations` counter, and moved the `print()` out of the loop so that you only see the final result.

Here is the modified code:

```
def newtonsMethod(poly, x_, epsilon, timeout):
    """Calculating root of polynomial using newton's Method."""
    iterations = 0
    while abs(evaluatePoly(poly, x_)) > epsilon and \
          abs(evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly), x_)) > epsilon and \
          iterations < timeout:
        x_ = x_ - (evaluatePoly(poly, x_) / evaluatePoly(findDerivative(poly), x_))
        iterations += 1
    print(x_)
```

Here is a sample run using the `findDerivative()` and `evaluatePoly()` functions that you provided:

```
>>> xpr = [0, 0, 5]
>>> newtonsMethod(xpr, -1, 1e-20, 1000)
-2.91038304567e-11
>>> evaluatePoly(xpr, -2.91038304567e-11)
4.235164736261692e-21
```

## Update:

I have looked at the new function definition that you posted, and found the problem. The fundamental problem in your code is that `value` and `deriv` are evaluated only once, outside the loop. You need to move these two statements inside of the loop so that they can be updated after each iteration. Also, I would move the assigment to `x_` to the end of the loop so that your first guess gets tested before it is updated. You can simplify the bodies of your `if` statements a bit also. As it is, when you escape the function due to an unacceptably small value for `deriv` or a timeout, your function reports `True`. I assume that you want it to report `False`. Here is how I modified your code:

```
def newtonsMethod(poly, x_, epsilon, timeout):
    """Calculating root of polynomial using newton's Method."""
    deriv_poly = findDerivative(poly)
    count = 1
    while True:
        deriv = evaluatePoly(deriv_poly, x_)
        value = evaluatePoly(poly, x_)

        if abs(value) < epsilon:
            boolean = True
            return (x_, boolean)

        if abs(deriv) < epsilon or count > timeout:
            boolean = False
            return (x_, boolean)

        x_ -= value / deriv
        count += 1
```

Here is a sample run:

```
>>> xpr = [0, 0, 5]
>>> newtonsMethod(xpr, -1, 1e-20, 1000)
(-2.9103830456733704e-11, True)
>>> evaluatePoly(xpr, -2.9103830456733704e-11)
4.235164736271502e-21
```

I am guessing that the slight difference between these results and the earlier results is due to rounding errors and the differing procedures for calculation.

Comment: So I tried it out as you suggested, but the loop is printing out "none". I have never come across this response before; what could it mean?

Comment: What are the functions `evaluatePoly()`and `findDerivative()` returning?

Comment: evaluatePoly is evaluating a polynomial for variable x_ or x (e.g. 3x^2 + 1 =  4 if x = 1) and findDerivative is finding the derivative of a polynomial and returning it as a list (e.g. derivative of 4x^0 + 3x^1 + 1x^2 is returned as [3, 2])

Comment: Is it possible that `findDerivative()` is returning an empty list to `evaluatePoly()`? Can you add the rest of your code to your question so that we can see it? Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @schCivil-- I have completely overhauled my answer. Please read.

Comment: Thank you so much for revising your answer. I actually revised my question to show more specifications the assignment required that I failed to mention before (I did not understand the info was needed until your revised answer). But I appreciate the code you revised; it help me greatly understanding where my code could have gone wrong before @David Bowling

Comment: @schCivil-- Happy to help-- consider upvoting or accepting my answer if it was useful :)

Comment: @schCivil-- I have updated my answer to address your new function.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I actually had a similar code when I was playing around, but my boolean wasn't returning right so I moved on; but I see where I went wrong before. Thank you so much for your continued help and I hope you have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) commented, using a simpler `while` condition (possible just `while True`) is almost always better than a very complicated condition that can't even fit on one line. You'd put the actual logic for ending the loop in one or more `if` statements inside the loop body:

```
while True:  # no condition here
    # do stuff

    if failure_condition1():
        break        # stop looping

    if success_condition():
        return result()        # another way to stop looping is to return a value

    if failure_condition2():
        raise SomeException()     # you could also raise an exception on failure

    # do other stuff
```

Any combination of `return`, `raise` or `break` could be correct for your function, it depends exactly what you want to do when each condition is met (and what you want the API to be).

One advantage to this style of loop is that you can check the conditions wherever it makes sense in your algorithm. The test doesn't have to be at the start of the loop (which often requires you to initialize your variables with made up values that will pass the condition the first time through).

Here's how I'd apply this kind of control flow in your specific problem:

```
def newtonsMethod(poly, x_, timeout):
    """Calculating root of polynomial using newton's Method."""
    estimate = 0
    epsilon = 1e-20
    deriv_poly = findDerivative(poly)
    while True:
        value = evaluatePoly(poly, x_)
        if abs(value) < epsilon:
            return x_
        deriv = evaluatePoly(deriv_poly, x_)
        if abs(deriv) < epsilon or estimate > timeout:
            raise ValueError("Not converging")
        #print(x_, value, deriv)
        x_ -= value / deriv
        estimate += 1
```

Note that we only need to call `evaluatePoly` twice per pass, since we save the results rather than recomputing them.

I also fixed a few errors in your code. I use `estimate` as a counter, rather than an alias for `x_` and no longer have `epsilon` as a parameter that is overwritten in the function body (you also had it misspelled as `epislon`).

Comment: failure_condition1() would have to be a variable wouldn't it? or is that a sort of function acting as an if statement?

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, I understand what you mean. I'm so sorry, thank you

Comment: So I did as you suggested and rewrote my code with the if statements. And I understand how it should work and all, but my code is crashing now; the loop keeps running through and I end up having o terminate it or it just crashes. I was wondering if you have any suggestions for the while loop condition besides True or False?

Comment: I've edited to add my implementation of your function with the kind of control flow I was suggesting. There were some other errors in your code, such as `estimate` not being used in a sensible way (as a counter). I'd guess the problems you had were related to those separate issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I actually revised my question to show more specifications the assignment required that I failed to mention before. But I appreciate the code you provided in your answer; it helped me greatly in understanding how the code should work to provide what I needed  @Blckknght